# Where would I keep my .txt files for inclusion in a Flex app?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm working on a flex app, and I have Flash & AS3 experience up to now. I have text file I need to request using URLLoader, so I placed it in the same directory as the SWF

```
deploy > maps > map1.txt
```

but when run the SWF I get the following error

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file:///Users/him/Documents/Clients/Geekery/Bounce/deploy/Bounce.swf cannot access local resource /maps/map1.txt. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
    at flash.net::URLStream/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/load()
    at com.geekery.Bounce::BounceMap()
    at Bounce/loadMap()
    at Bounce()
```

Which seems odd to me. Is there a special place I should be keeping files like this? Or is there some way I can allow files to be loaded form the same directory as the SWF?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a relative or absolute url? Have you tried `loader.load( new URLRequest( 'maps/map1.txt' ) )` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is static, you can use the @Embed tag to do this.  See [this example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/24/embedding-eternal-files-using-embed/).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a *crossdomain.xml* to set the permissions for the .swf application on the same server. More info at below links

[Cross-domain policy file specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html)

[loadPolicyFile()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile%28%29)

If this is not really what you are looking for then you can just go for the [Embed] solution.